# What's wrong with linux/ext2_fs.h? I have included <linux/fs.h>

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu

While looking for a solution to my problem I have seen that this question has been asked before... However the solution that has always been offered is `#include <linux/fs.h>`, which I have and I am still getting this error.

Running Ubuntu 13.10 with cc compiler.

When I try to compile my program.c I receive the following error:

```
fatal error: linux/ext2_fs.h: No such file or directory
 #include <linux/ext2_fs.h>
                        ^
```

My header file includes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/ext2_fs.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
```

Comment: Somewhere in your code you have the line "#include <linux/ext2.h>". That file doesn't exist, so you can't include it.

Comment: I am sorry, I copied and pasted the wrong error output. I have fixed it now. Sorry about that.

Comment: Did you try: `ls -l /usr/include/linux/ext2_fs.h`?  If it says it isn't there, it probably isn't there.

Comment: Another question is, for what reason are you trying to include `ext2_fs.h` (which, as far as I can tell, doesn't exist at all)? Maybe if you ask about the original problem we can help.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem using `gcc` with Ubuntu 15.10 and solved it like this:

`sudo apt-get install e2fslibs-dev`